# to set value parent page's frame from popup

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I want to set label's value from popup.But label is in frame and I dont know how to achieve it from popup.  From parent page,i get this label by following javascript function.

But when I use this function in popup page, I cant find topframe.Do u have any solution about how to success it?

```
if (window.parent.document.getElementById('lbl')) 
{
    window.parent.document.getElementById('lbl').innerText = sender.getSelectedItem().get_text();
}
else
{ 
    window.parent.frames['topFrame'].document.getElementById('lbl').innerText = sender.getSelectedItem().get_text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.parent
```

refers to your popup-window itself.

Try

```
opener.frames['topFrame'].document.getElementById()
```

instead - 'opener' refers to your main-window out of a popup.

Comment: when i want to get window.opener in debug windows,i see that it is undefined.

Comment: Not "window.opener": just "opener". Maybe it's needed that you open it like "var myWindow = window.open("url");"

Comment: Just opener doesnt work too,it says undefined.I open my popup by modalpopup maybe it doesnt work cause of modalpopup...

Comment: Somehow strange - my popup works fine with opener and my german source for javascript (http://de.selfhtml.org) also says so. But cool that you found a solution :-) Maybe it's really modalpopup...

Answer (score 0):

`window.parent.top.frames.document` works